Approximating the identity with two singular matrices
I am working on a ML project where I would need to find a $n \times m$ matrix $A$ and  a $m \times n$ matrix $B$ such that $n<m$ (ideally $n=72$ and $m=429$) and $BA$ is as close to the identity as possible (with whatever distance).
I tried approximating it with least squares with a certain loss that emphasizes the diagonal, I got the elements in the diagonal to be very close to $1$ but the elements outside the diagonal are around $10^{-2}$, I would love if there is a way to find better matrices where the product makes the elements outside the diagonal in $10^{-6}$ order.

For the usual sum-of-squares distance, the closest you can possibly get is a distance of $\sqrt{429 - 72} \approx 18.9$, and the "closest" matrices are obtained whenever $B$ has orthonormal columns and $A = B^T$.

If the diagonal elements are all close to 1, then the Gershgorin circle theorem tells you that for at least $m - n$ rows, the sum  of the off-diagonal row-entries will be more than $1$ (at least, more than the associated diagonal entry), which means that they average out to about $1/429 > 10^{-3}$.

@BenGrossmann do you know how I can achieve that 1/429 bound with elements close to 1 in all the diagonals?

Sorry for the delay. I suspect that something could be done using the projection matrices that I discuss here, i.e. one could find $A,B$ such that $BA$ is equal to that kind of projection matrix with the entries scaled to give 1's on the diagonal. If I find time I may put a detailed answer down explaining that in further detail.
